# When do I conjugate a verb after a verb?

Tags: verbos, conjugación

When I was studying, I came across this issue that bugged me. In many sentences, a verb after a verb won't be conjugated(amos, ías, an, etc.) Here is an example:

"pretendía estar dormido"

Why isn't estar conjugated? Shouldn't it be conjugated to estuve/estaba? If you can, please explain when I should conjugate / NOT conjugate verbs. Thanks for your help and feedback.

Comment: Be careful with pretend/pretender: https://spanish.yabla.com/lesson-Pretender-Beware-of-false-cognates-66

Comment: It wouldn't be conjugated in English either. A better example would be good. pretender in Spanish means: to intend. /I intended/to be asleep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In verb phrases formed by a main verb and an infinitive and/or a verb ending in -ando/-endo (present participle), only the main verb is tensed and conjugated.

The only case I can think of where a conjugated verb can be followed by another conjugated verb is that of both verbs referring to different grammatical persons, with the second verb belonging to a content (noun) clause having a tacit conjunction "que" (that). This structure is rather formal or literary and should always be avoided in everyday speech:

- Hablaba sobre cómo **imaginaba** (que) **sería** su vida. (He spoke about what he imagined his life would be like.)

The only circumstance where this structure is more usual occurs when the content clause is embedded within a relative clause (in which case there is a relative "que" and the conjunction "que" continues to be omitted). This phenomenon also occurs in English:

- Tenía una vida que siempre **imaginaba** (que) **sería** distinta. (He had a life he always **imagined would be** different.)